# Skip-gram implementation of word2vec in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, word2vec, softmax

I try to implement some different models of word2vec in tensorflow for university. But i'm not sure how to understand the [skip-gram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAgoj.png) model or how to implement what I think in tensorflow.

If I have a window size ( C ) and one-hot-vectors of size ( V ) skip-gram predicts C Vectors of size V right?

Now my first idea was to predict a vector with C * V dimensions which is concatinated from C one-hot-vectors. But if I do that, the softmax can't optimize it anymore.

To solve that I have had the idea to split my big vector into C smaller vectors and use the softmax on these smaller vectors. Calculate the loss for each of these smaller vectors and create a optimizer for each of these vectors. And in the end run the session with C optimizers in it.

But in my mind it is not a good idea to feed more than one optimizer to the session? Am I right? Is that really a way to implement skip-gram. Or how does it work?

Comment: I think I have found the solution. I have to train the neural network C times for each fokusword. One time vor each context word.

Comment: Using multiple optimizers in a single session or session.run call is perfectly fine.